# Receiving AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' on Amazon Price Tracker

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

Here is the snippet of code that is meant to return text from the html id of product title and then same for price but apparently it can't access the html code of the amazon product page.

```
def getPrice():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    print(title)
    print(price)
```

The error in the title of the question is thrown in these lines:

```
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
```

Comment: Which line is throwing? The error message is telling you that one of the soup nodes you are looking for on the page doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, you need to figure out whether your code is throwing on title or price. Then inspect the HTML that you're fetching and find out if the node is actually missing, or the value of the id has changed

Comment: its throwing title, I added price only after the error to see if that would work (I commented out the title line when I did that but still to no avail). So basically the soup.find method is unable to find the id="productTitle"

Comment: You can quickly debug by printing soup to an html file and then inspect the page. It may well be the case that amazon is returning unexpected HTML, i.e. you're being blocked

Comment: Can you explain an example of how to do the following "debug by printing soup to an html file and then inspect the page". Yes that does make sense but the tutorial I'm following was made recently (month or two ago) and they had no problem receiving the info.

Comment: `with open('test.html', 'w') as f: 
   f.write(str(soup))`. then open the file that you have just written in your browser

Comment: I'm new to Python/coding in general so I'm not quite sure where I would put that snippet of code in reference to the rest of my code blocks

Comment: Just underneath `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')` and then comment `title` and `price`

Comment: I received this back
 open('test.html', 'w') as f: f.write(str(soup))
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're missing `with`. Also make sure `f.write...` is on the line below `with open..` with 4 spaces indentation

Comment: got it, now it says this
NameError: name 'title' is not defined

Comment: Comment both `print` as well

Comment: getting the same error 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: You haven't commented the two `soup.find...` lines in your code then. I'd also suggest to use an IDE with syntax highlighting and linter which should flag these kinds of things.

Comment: is there any way I can send you my full code so yo can see the situation better? maybe in a chat or a git repository

Comment: Can you see my github profile from here? If so try to send me a message there. Hope we are not breaking any rules

Comment: yes I see it but I can't message you for some reason, I just followed you. I can post my repository so you can see the full code though its not that long

Comment: Alright go for it

Comment: I just shared it on my GitHub profile, can you see it?

Comment: I can see the repo but there seems to be no code in it

Comment: I see, check now

Comment: Posted an issue